# Dragging item gets hidden when overflow-y is used

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I created a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u98dtf4s/)** to demonstrate the problem (also can be run inside this question, below).

I have a sidebar of playing card images that I want to drag into a main area. The sidebar holds a lot of cards so I want it to be scrollable. However, when I give it a scroll feature, then when I drag a card, it gets hidden when I drag it out of the sidebar.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngDraggable']);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {


});
```

```css
#gallery-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/master/ngDraggable.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div id="gallery-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <img ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="hi" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="true" class="card" src="http://www.download32.com/images/screen/vector_playing_cards-467278.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <img ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="hi" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="true" class="card" src="http://www.download32.com/images/screen/vector_playing_cards-467278.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <img ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="hi" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="true" class="card" src="http://www.download32.com/images/screen/vector_playing_cards-467278.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <img ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="hi" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="true" class="card" src="http://www.download32.com/images/screen/vector_playing_cards-467278.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <img ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="hi" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="true" class="card" src="http://www.download32.com/images/screen/vector_playing_cards-467278.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <img ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="hi" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="true" class="card" src="http://www.download32.com/images/screen/vector_playing_cards-467278.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <img ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="hi" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="true" class="card" src="http://www.download32.com/images/screen/vector_playing_cards-467278.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                 <h2> Drop Area </h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I comment out overflow, like

```
/*overflow-y: scroll;*/
```

in the CSS, it now works.

How can I both have a scrolling sidebar and drag items out of it?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you... are you using a modern Chrome browser?

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/u98dtf4s/

Comment: I have the same problem. Everything out of container with `overflow: scroll` will be hidden.

Comment: `overflow: scroll;` works like an `overflow: hidden;` but with a scroll bar. That means you wont be able to pass the scroll because it will hide your element. I think you need to try a different approach.

Comment: I have implemented your example with a `ng-drag-clone` directive. I also implemented the drag and drop zones data arrays and data move functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**To drag objects between zones with scrolled or hidden overflows, you need a to create clone div between the drag div and the drop div using the `ng-drag-clone`**

```
        <div ng-drag-clone="">
            <img ng-src="{{clonedData .link}}" width="100px">
        </div>
```

### check my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dalper01/r36f3naf/)

I've tried to update your code, but quickly to demonstrate the point:

---

**I noticed you did not create any way for the drop zone to render or store the data being passed.**

I created a cards array and a cardsDrop array to store the data.

I also implemented `onDropComplete` function to push the card object into cardsDrop

```
$scope.onDropComplete = function (data, evt) {
    var index = $scope.cards.indexOf(data);
    if (index == -1) $scope.cardsDrop.push(data);
}
```

and a `onDragComplete` function to remove a card from the original deck (for some applications, this is optional... sometimes you want a list to drag from that does not remove options):

```
$scope.onDragComplete = function (data, evt) {
    console.log("133", "$scope", "onDragSuccess1", "", evt);
    var index = $scope.cards.indexOf(data);
    if (index > -1) {
        $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

and I used `ng-repeat` to render each deck in the drag zone

```
                    <div class="row" ng-repeat="card in cards">
                        <img src="http://www.download32.com/images/screen/vector_playing_cards-467278.png" alt="" vertical-scroll="false" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="card" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)" ng-center-anchor="true" width="100px">
                    </div>
```

and drop zones:

```
        <div style="min-height: 300px;" class="col-xs-5" ng-drop="true" ng-scroll="false" ng-drag-move="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete($data,$event)">
            <draggableClone></draggableClone>
             <h2> Drop Area </h2>

            <div ng-repeat="card in cardsDrop" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)" class="card">
                <img src="http://www.download32.com/images/screen/vector_playing_cards-467278.png" class="card" alt="" width="100px">
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

In addition, I have added some styling to the ng-drag and ng-drop.

Comment: thanks for adding so much. The snippet however has some weird behaviour when dragging a card

Comment: @Imray , the stack demo is a little off, but try my Fiddle        http://jsfiddle.net/y1o0oqjw/6/

Comment: where did you find `ng-drag-clone`?

Comment: I can't figure out how to drag something other than a King... any tips?

Comment: @Imray, the clone div should contain a likeness to what you want to drag. If you need the image to be dynamic (which I would expect), make the src a model variable and on drag-begin event, make the src of the clone to be the same src. If that sounds confusing,  modify my Plunkr with an idea of what you want to do, then post a comment with a link. Once I see it, I can make suggestions and modify...

Comment: I updated the Fiddle with different cards. Each card I start to drag, becomes a King. http://jsfiddle.net/y1o0oqjw/7/

Comment: @Imray, check my updated Fiddle. I used ngDragClone's `scope.clonedata` and I updated the drop area to use `data.link.` If you're happy with it, I'll update my answer  http://jsfiddle.net/dalper01/r36f3naf/

Comment: that works now.. makes sense. I didn't notice the `clonedData` item

Comment: @Imray, I didn't point it out because I wasn't sure what your end use would be yet.

Comment: Weird problem... when I scroll down and then drag, the dragged card does not drag under the cursor. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @Imray, that's an issue with all draggables. There always a way to implement scroll-drag behavior. It may require extending the directive -- forking the repo and adding that kind of behavior. It's an interesting issue. Make a plunkr / fiddle and post it as a question. LMK when you do.

Comment: I'm referring to the Fiddle you made. When a scroll down some of the page, and then click on a card and start dragging, the card is dragged pretty far from the cursor's position, even when I click right in the middle of the card.

Comment: @Imray, check this new Fiddle, does it solve your issue? http://jsfiddle.net/dalper01/r36f3naf/2/

Comment: @Imray I found this bug reported on the **fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable** github: https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/pull/143. mattgoldspink did exactly what I was suggesting, forked the repo and adjusted ngDragClone directive to account for scrolling offsets. If you check the  ngDraggable reference on my new Fiddle, it now points to **mattgoldspink/ngDraggable**. Make that change to your own code.

Answer (score 8):

The `ngDraggable` library you're using does not support adding the element to a parent element (like document.body) once you start dragging. You *need* that, otherwise the element can never leave the sidebar and keep on being visible. That's how CSS works.

What you could do is use another library that supports adding the draggable element to another element, like jQuery UI:

```
app.directive('draggable', function() {
    return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        $element.draggable({
            appendTo: 'body',
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                // Handle new position
            }
        });

    };
});
```

There are probably AngularJS wrappers for Jquery UI out there that do this for you in a more declarative style, or other ngDraggable alternatives that support this.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't support adding it to a parent element? Every element other than `<html>` has a parent element

Comment: As long as the draggable element is a child of it's current parent (gallery-container), it won't be able to move out of it because of the CSS applied to it (overflow-y: scroll). It would only work with overflow: visibe. This is a known issue, so what some libraries do is to add an option that allows this: while dragging the element, they temporarily move the element to a parent element like the body so that you can drag it anywhere. Your library does not implement that option.

Comment: Yes, the draggable elements will be "lost" in the parent's overflow. To get around that you can use a clone that's bound to neither drag nor drop element.